# PoE hat troubles

Tags: poe

I have three Raspberry Pis, all three with PoE hats. One of them works perfectly. The second one is completely non-functional. The third worked for about a day, then stopped working. All three are plugged in to the same Ubiquiti PoE switch (a UniFi Switch 8 POE-150W). The working Pi works on all ports. The non-working Pis don't work on any ports.

Could I really have two bad Pi hats out of three total? What else could be wrong with my setup that I can fix? Soldering anything is a non-starter - I have bad eyes and not nearly enough patience for that.

**Update** with info from a comment:
All three Pis will boot normally with an external power supply. The working one and one of the failing Pis are model 3 B+'s, the other failing Pi is a model 4. When I hook up the PoE cable, no lights come on and the Pis do not boot.

Comment: No functional meaning what?  Do any lights come on, do they attempt to boot? do they boot using a normal power supply?

Comment: All three Pis will boot normally with an external power supply. The working one and one of the failing Pis are model 3 B+'s, the other failing Pi is a model 4. When I hook up the PoE cable, no lights come on and the Pis do not boot.

Comment: If ya have a multimeter, and some electronics experience, I would do a little testing to see where you have power on the hat. Certainly seems like you may have a couple of bad ones, but without further testing, no way of knowing if its a quick/easy fix or not.

Comment: No answer but an observation - I only have 1 RPI 4 with an official POE hat. I find that on the ubiquity controller the web user interface will display the amount of power (in W) that is being drawn through a given POE port. This is one way to see if power is consumed. After a shutdown now at the cli, the PI4 will consume a small amount of power according to the web UI.